# Reactjs firing AJAX call multiple times a button is clicked (only want 1 per click!)

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, redux, axios

I have a simple React app that has a form in it and upon the user clicking submit, post the form to a server. Simple enough.

But React is firing the AJAX call multiple times (4-5 usually) in immediate succession, creating all sorts of issues. I don't know why - I assume it has something to do so React's lifecycle, but I am not sure.

I am using axios as a AJAX library, so perhaps the problem is with that library (I think not though).

Here is the method that fires the code:

```
submitEvent(event) {
event.preventDefault();
const apiQueryString = `api/event?${qs.stringify(this.state)}`;
if (this.state.event_title === undefined) {
  alert('Event title is required!');
} else {
  axios.post(apiQueryString)
      .then((result) => {
        this.state.id = result.data[0];
        store.dispatch({
          type: 'ADD_SINGLE_EVENT',
          event: this.state,
        });
        alert('Success creating event!');
        this.setState({}); // clear out old values
        browserHistory.push('/');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        alert('Error with database! See console for output.');
      });
}
```

And this is the button that fires this function:

`<button onClick={this.submitEvent} className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>`

The entire file's source code is [here](https://github.com/benrondeau/musician-cms-reactjs/blob/master/src/app/components/newEvent.jsx#L18), and the working page is [here](https://musician-cms.herokuapp.com/new).

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Try adding `onSubmit` prop inside the form, such as: `<form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}` to prevent the standard form behaviour. Let me know if that works for you and I'll add it as an answer

Comment: Note: You should always specify the button type (submit or button) explicitly since different browsers have different defaults...

Comment: @rauliyohmc Did not seem to work.

Comment: What is happen if you remove the [highlighted code here](https://github.com/benrondeau/musician-cms-reactjs/blob/master/src/app/components/newEvent.jsx#L27toL30)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the middleware. In the method that handled this AJAX request on the backend, a new item was being inserted into the database on the successful callback of req.getValidationResult(). This success callback was being called twice, resulting in multiple database inserts.

Comment: It actually created 6 events in my database, so perhaps it is on the backend?

Comment: ok, i submitted it three times. So yes, it must be in your backend. Are you using nodejs on the backend? If so, I can help you out if you post that code.

Comment: Here is the server file: https://github.com/benrondeau/musician-cms-reactjs/blob/master/server.js#L94

Comment: I think getValidationResult must be the issue. It seems like its triggering the callback twice. Try without it and see if it solves the problem?

Comment: The issue is `getValidationResult` method. It is being fired many times. Troubleshooting now....

Answer (score 0):

I would move the submission from the button to the form. Any button inside a form will trigger the form to submit on click, unless that button has `type=button` attribute. In your case the button click would cause the form to submit, which would then submit a form GET request to your current page.

Your `submitEvent` method is already preventing the default event, which should stop the native form submit from happening.

```
<form onSubmit={submitEvent}>
  // this button is inside form so clicking it will trigger form submit
  <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one button in your form and you don't specify it's type (button/submit) by default it will be a submit button.
So it is better to use onSubmit instead of onClick here.